# $\nabla b \times \hat{z}$ using index notation

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, index-notation

$b$ is a scalar, $\hat z$ is the unit vector in the vertical direction and I need to evaluate a vector $$\vec{v} = \nabla b \times \hat{z}.$$

What I have done so far:

$$\vec{v} = \nabla b \times \hat{z} = \epsilon_{123}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2}e_3e_1 + \epsilon_{213}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1}e_3e_2 = \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2}\delta_{31} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1}\delta_{32} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1}$$

which is definitely wrong because $\vec{v}$ should be a vector. It might be something obvious I can't find but I would like to know exactly each component of $\vec{v}$.

Comment: what is $\hat z$?

Comment: unit vector in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Einstein summation its
$$ \vec v _i= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j b \hat z_k$$
so
$$ \vec v = \epsilon_{1jk} \partial_j b \hat z_k \hat x + \epsilon_{2jk} \partial_j b \hat z_k \hat y+ \epsilon_{3jk} \partial_j b \hat z_k \hat z$$
Since the only nonzero component of $\hat z$ is $\hat z_3 = 1$,
\begin{align}
 \vec v 
&= \epsilon_{1j3} \partial_j b \hat z_3 \hat x + \epsilon_{2j3} \partial_j b \hat z_3 \hat y+ \epsilon_{3j3} \partial_j b \hat z_3 \hat z \\
&=  \epsilon_{1j3} \partial_j b \hat x + \epsilon_{2j3} \partial_j b  \hat y+ \epsilon_{3j3} \partial_j b \hat z\end{align}
The $\hat z$ component is zero because $\epsilon_{3j3}= 0$ which we could have directly seen before any computation from the fact that $\vec a\times \vec b $ and $\vec b$ are perpendicular. Now since $\epsilon_{123}=1$ and $\epsilon_{213}=-1$ are the only relevant non-zero terms,

$$ \vec v = \partial_2 b \hat x  - \partial_1 b \hat y$$

It seems your mistake was saying that the third component of $\hat z$ is $e_3$, but a component of a vector is not another vector, it is a scalar.

Comment: so $\vec{v} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial y} \hat{x} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} \hat{y}$, because $\hat{z}\hat{x} = -\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}\hat{y} = \hat{x}$?

Comment: No, $\hat z_3$ is a number, equal to 1. There is no product like $\hat z \hat x $ anywhere. I've edited to make that clearer

Comment: Got it! The mistake was to assume that $\hat{z}_3$ is $e_3$

Answer (score 0):

In cartesian coordinates you have
$$
v=\nabla b \times w
= \sum_{i,j,k=1}^3
\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_ib\,w_je_k
$$
where $e_k$ are the basis vectors.
Try expanding the sum. There should be $27$ terms, $21$ of which will be zero because of the $\epsilon_{ijk}$ terms, so only $6$ will survive.

For example, the first two terms are
$$
v=
\epsilon_{111}\partial_1b\,w_1e_1
+
\epsilon_{112}\partial_1b\,w_1e_2
+\dots
$$

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried to do in the post. From your example $v$ is an unit vector in the vertical direction, so I end up with $\epsilon_{123}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2}e_3e_1 + \epsilon_{213}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1}e_3e_2$, right?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My notarion clashes with yours (I originally used $v$ for something different) Now I edited the post.

Comment: how did you end up with the $e_3e_1$ terms? every term should have only one of the $e_k$.

Comment: I got confused and assumed $\hat{z}_3$ is $e_3$. I think Calvin Khor found it.

Comment: @iurysimoes-sousa Right, $\hat z=e_3$ is a vector with components $\hat z = \hat z_1e_1 + \hat z_2e_2 + \hat z_3e_3$, so $\hat z_1=\hat z_2 = 0$ and $\hat z_3=1$.